# How do I select an element within an XSLT template parameter?

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSLT Template:

```
    <xsl:template name="foo">
    <xsl:param name="arg1">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="arg2" />
    <xsl:param name="arg3" />
    <xsl:call-template name="bar">
        <xsl:with-param name="arg1"><xsl:value-of select="$arg1" /></xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="arg2"><xsl:copy-of select="$arg2" /></xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="arg3"><!-- what do I put here? --></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Now arg3 is an xml snippit.  I only want to select an element within arg3 to pass to bar as arg3.  How do I select individual nodes from a parameter?  I tried , but it did not work.

Please don't suggest sending the value of arg3/qux instead of arg3.  There's a good reason for this, but that's beyond the point of this question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _but it did not work_? Were any error messages given? @James Johnson's edited solution will likely be what you want but, without any error messages, it's hard to provide help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the XML snippet looks like, but you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$arg3/first_name" />
```

**EDIT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxsl">

    <xsl:template match="/">               
        <xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($arg3)/first_name" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What are you using to process your XSLT?  Java doesn't seem to like this. :(

Comment: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: Going out of my depth a little here, but try using a node-set.

Comment: I'm going to play the lottery now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just treat $arg3 as a node, works for me.

```
<xsl:call-template name="bar">
    <xsl:with-param name="arg1"><xsl:value-of select="$arg1" /></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="arg2"><xsl:copy-of select="$arg2" /></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="arg3" select="$arg3/sub-node"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```